# project explorer is empty

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have added project explorer view to my own rcp application. It is visible in the window and I can create a new project using new project wizard.

However there are a couple of problems:

- first when project is created project explorer does not show project name, there is an empty row (just like when tree node has empty label);
- the second when I restart application there are no projects shown in project explorer at all (workspace is not cleared between application runs);

I searched for my problem and all solutions I found refer to supplying default page input. I overrode default input in the following way:

```
@Override
    public IAdaptable getDefaultPageInput() {
        return ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
    }
```

However it did not help, problem remained intact.

There are following plugins referenced from my one:

```
org.eclipse.ui,
org.eclipse.core.runtime,
org.eclipse.ui.ide;bundle-version="3.7.0",
org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources;bundle-version="3.4.300",
org.eclipse.core.resources;bundle-version="3.7.100",
org.eclipse.ui.navigator;bundle-version="3.5.100"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found root cause of the problem. There were missing adapter mappings in my application. So solution is to call `IDE.registerAdapters()` to register all necessary adapters. After that call I managed to fill view with some content. Victory!!!!

Comment: Another problem related to CNF viewer is missing project icons, so may be this will be useful for somebody: there is bug created at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=234252 and blog entry at http://francisu.wordpress.com/2008/05/27/magic-required-to-use-the-common-navigator-in-an-rcp-application/